# How to reorder strings inside Pandas data frame and insert new ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like below. Data type of `Output` is string.

```
ID  Output
1   ab 1, bc 2, ac 5, at 0, abc 0 
2   ab 0, ac 5, at 0
3   ac 5, bc 0, atn 0
```

As you can see, in row2, `bc` is skipped while the overall order stays the same. However, in row3, the order differs. How do I first insert the missing categories and then reorder the strings in the data frame? In other words, how may I get an intermediate data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  Output
1   ab 1, bc 2, ac 5,  at 0,  abc 0, atn  
2   ab 0, bc,   ac 5,  at 0, abc,   atn
3   ab,   bc 0, ac 5,  at,   abc,   atn 0
```

So eventually I can perform the below operation:

```
x = df['Output'].str.split(",",expand=True,)
x.columns = x.iloc[0, :].str.extract(r"^(.*)\s+")[0]
x = x.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r"^(.*\s+)", ""))
df=pd.concat([df, x], axis=1)
```

To reach this ideal data frame:

```
ID  ab    bc   ac   at    abc    atn
1   1     2    5    0     0      None
2   0     None 5    0     None   None
3   None  0    5    None  None    0
```

Comment: What is the dtype of `Output` column? `string`?

Comment: Yes, it's string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can skip the part where the intermediate dataframe is created and directly approach to create the resulting dataframe. Here, we can use `str.findall` to find the token pairs e.g. `(ab, 1), (bc, 2)` etc. which can be used to create records corresponding to each row, where each record contains the column names as keys and corresponding values, then we can easily create the resulting dataframe from these records.

```
pd.DataFrame([*df['Output'].str.findall(r'(\S+)\s(\d+)').map(dict)], dtype=float)
```

---

```
    ab   bc   ac   at  abc  atn
0  1.0  2.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  NaN
1  0.0  NaN  5.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  0.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! +1.  Can you get 'ID' back as the dataframe index?

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you good sir! I guess we can simply join/assign the resulting dataframe with `ID` column .

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I'm not seeing where the `dict` is defined for the `.map(dict)`

Comment: @jch `dict` is a `builtin` in python, and is used to represent `dictionary`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I ask because when I try to recreate a portion of your excellent answer - `[*df['Output'].str.findall(r'(\S+)\s(\d+)').map(dict)]` after adding the `.map(dict)` part I get:  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @jch What is your python & pandas version?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma 1.0.5 and Python 3.7.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231475/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-jch).

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

- Split column `Output` by comma into list;
- explode `Output` column;
- Split `Output` column by whitespace;
- pivot the table;

Code:

```
df = df.assign(Output = df.Output.str.split(', ')).explode('Output')
pd.concat([df.ID, df.Output.str.split(' ', expand=True)], axis=1) \
  .pivot('ID', 0, 1)

#0    ab  abc ac   at  atn   bc
#ID                            
#1     1    0  5    0  NaN    2
#2     0  NaN  5    0  NaN  NaN
#3   NaN  NaN  5  NaN    0    0
```